# Problem of large size of .apk file in android?

Tags: android

I have a problem that arise due to large size and no. of images in app, my app stopped installing on emulator. It gives an error report " No Space Left". Size of .apk file is about 60MB. Now, I would like to ask the following questions:

- What could be done in this situation, so that it gets installed and doesn't gives this error?
- Does android market allow to install app of this size?

Thanks in advance

Comment: wats ur application size?remove some other application and try to install it.

Comment: @Jinda :there is no application installed, I am recently testing on emulator and app size is about 200MB and .apk about 60MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Present limit of android market is 50 MB. so you can compress your images with some image compression and if you have used video or audio then also you can compress so you can achieved 50 MB. many compression tool is available.

Comment: Can I use jpeg as compression tool and does it will support images in drawable folder

Comment: @ Nik.... : I am using .jpg format but still the size of .apk file is same as before

Comment: @Nikki : http://download.cnet.com/Advanced-JPEG-Compressor/3000-12511_4-10053503.html this link is .jpg compress software so you can compress your image and replace your current images. If you used audio & video file in you application same search google for that compression tool and compress audio & video and replace with current and after create your APK file i am sure you can achieved 50MB.

Comment: @ Nik.... : But jpeg format doesn't support transparency in images and I want images to be transparent from sides and on compression it also gives me black background which must not happen. Do you know any solution for this problem

Comment: @Nikki: have you used audio & video file in your app?

Comment: @ Nik.... : audio .mp3 files are used but they are of very less size and it will not effect anything on compressing them as .apk file is of 60MB and audio files are of max. 2MB size

Comment: if you have backgrounds you can use 9-patch images http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 3):

The limitation of android market now is 50MB. 
What you can do is out some resources on the server and download them on demand. You can promt the user that the app is going to download large amount of data, so that user can use wifi to do it.

Comment: But I don't have to use server side then is there any option availiable for this problem

Comment: @ Vladimir Ivanov: I can't use server as it will take the loading time to load images and I have to change images regularly as app is similar to somewhat gaming in which images are used regularly one after another. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

At the 24:10 mark in the video from Google IO, large apks in the market were announced, coming in June:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-market-for-developers.html

Answer (score 0):

Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB. For most applications, this is plenty of space for all the application's code and assets. However, some apps need more space for high-fidelity graphics, media files, or other large assets. Previously, if your app exceeded 50MB, you had to host and download the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app. Hosting and serving the extra files can be costly, and the user experience is often less than ideal. To make this process easier for you and more pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

Here are the steps required for setting up expansion files in Android:

1. First, open the Android SDK Manager, expand Extras and download:

   - Google Play Licensing Library package
   - Google Play APK Expansion Library package
2. Declare the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <!-- Required to access Google Play Licensing -->  
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

   <!-- Required to download files from Google Play -->  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <!-- Required to keep CPU alive while downloading files (NOT to keep screen awake) -->  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

   <!-- Required to poll the state of the network connection  
       and respond to changes -->
   <uses-permission  
       android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <!-- Required to check whether Wi-Fi is enabled -->  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

   <!-- Required to read and write the expansion files on shared storage -->  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
3. Integrate libraries

   - Copy the source for the Downloader Library from `<sdk>/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/src` to your project.
   - Copy the sources from `<sdk>/extras/google/play_licensing/library/src` to your project.
   - Copy the sources from `<sdk>/extras/google/google_market_apk_expansion/zip_file/` to your project.
4. Now, create a new package named expansion and create `DownloaderService.java` inside the package.

   ```
   // DownloaderService.java
   public class DownloaderService extends com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloaderService {  
       public static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "<<YOUR PUBLIC KEY HERE>>"; // TODO Add public key
       private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[]{1, 4, -1, -1, 14, 42, -79, -21, 13, 2, -8, -11, 62, 1, -10, -101, -19, 41, -12, 18}; // TODO Replace with random numbers of your choice

       @Override
       public String getPublicKey() {
           return BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY;
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getSALT() {
           return SALT;
       }

       @Override
       public String getAlarmReceiverClassName() {
           return DownloaderServiceBroadcastReceiver.class.getName();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Create `DownloaderServiceBroadcastReceiver.java` extending `BoradcastReceiver` which will start the download service if the files need to downloaded.

   ```
   // DownloaderServiceBroadcastReceiver.java
   public class DownloaderServiceBroadcastReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {  
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           try {
               DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context, intent, DownloaderService.class);
           } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Start the download from your activity if expansion files are not available

   ```
   Intent launchIntent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
   Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getClass());
   intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

   if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
       for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
           intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
       }
   }

   // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from notification
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   // Request to start the download
   int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this, pendingIntent, DownloaderService.class);
   ```

For full details and code, take a look at [How to Set Up Android App to Support Expansion Files](http://sapandiwakar.in/how-to-set-up-android-app-to-support-expansion-files/).